# Cвязаный select в ajax jvascript

Tags: ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте! [Здесь](http://pyha.ru/articles/php/ajax-select/) есть код 2х полей. Как сделать три и более с подгрузкой друг друга?

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов. Опишу один из них.
Идея состоит в использовании id - *"sel_name-current_select-parent_select"*
Берем селект - `<select id="sel-region class="load_data">`, связвнный будет - `<select id="sel-country-region class="load_data">`. sel - просто имя связанной группы селектов.
для класса load_data пишем обработчик click. Забираем его id, через ф-ю split распарсиваем id. получаем все части id. Учавствуют только 2 последние. Далее по классу собираем все id. Каждый из них так же распарсиваем. Сравниваем чтоб current_select текущего было равно parent_select найденого id. Если совпадает - подгружаем в этот элемент наши option'ы, перед этим не забыв сделать аякс запрос и получить их список. Таким образом можно связвть сколько угодоно селектов. А дальше дело фантазии и задания - навести красоту и т.д.

Comment: Мне нужно понять смысл файла selects.js. Там идет выбор если Россия, то одна группа областей, если Украина, другая. Как продолжить скрипт, чтобы при выборе области можно было загрузить в поле район и т.д.?

Comment: Создаете файл с областями, по id выбранного региона - загружаете нужные районы, которые обозначте в массиве по id области. По аналогии с тем что есть...т.е. вам надо описать обработчик для id c регионами. $('#region_id').change(function (){});
так же создайте селект с id районов. и в него загружайте районы...